# Auto confirmation of event in calendar using .ics file

Tags: calendar

I have one .ics file in which there is some event in it and i m sending this to user. So when user clicks on the file it is asking him/her for the confirmation to add event. I just want to remove that stage. That means the event should get auto confirmed and set it in the user calendar.
If any other solution then also appreciated.
Thanks